# Infinite loop reading Java inputstream

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I have a question about java's InputStream.

I am reading data from a file like below:

```
FileInputStream xfis = new FileInputStream('filename')

int size = xfis.avaliable();
int len = 0 ;
byte[] buffer new byte[size];

while( (len = xfis.read(buffer) > -1 )
(
  //   process some logic
)

xfis.close();
....
```

And also running a batch program every minute:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream('filename')
FileLock flock = fos.getChannel().tryLock();

if(flock != null){
  fos.write()
  flock.release();
}

fos.close();
...
```

When both programs read and write at the same time the program that reads the file gets stuck in an infinite loop.

How can I solve that problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why the read would be in an infinite loop. The write is just going to do some writing and then stop, right?

Comment: while( (len = xfis.read(buffer) > 0 )...?

Comment: It looks like you are only locking when writing, not when reading. Try to get the lock before you read so you don't have two processes working on the same file at the same time (while one thinks it has exclusive access)

Answer (score 0):

`xfis.avialable()` is returning `0`.  When you try to read into a zero-length buffer, you always succeed and get a read length of `0`, not `-1`.  Buffer sizes should be independent of how many bytes are available.  You use the value returned by `xfis.read` to determine how much of the buffer was filled.

Try this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.max(1, size)];
```

Comment: thanks for your help. if you do not help , i will do night work today^^